# Differentiation of position vector wrt time

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I want to differentiate $\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}$ wrt t (time).
I know the following;
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \mathbf{\dot{r}}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} = {\dot{r}}$$
and so
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\frac{1}{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{r^2}\dot{r}$$
and putting this together gives;
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathbf{\dot{r}}}{r} - \frac{\dot{r}\mathbf{r}}{r^2}$$

Is this correct as I would have instinctively thought that since $\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r} = \mathbf{\hat{{r}}}$, the correct answer would be $\mathbf{\hat{\dot{r}}}$

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. You obtain
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathbf{\dot{r}}}{r} - \frac{\dot{r}\mathbf{r}}{r^2}=\frac{\mathbf{\dot{r}}r-\dot{r}\mathbf{r}}{r^2}$$
as direct differentiating in **ratio** shows.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  First, $\hat r(t)=\frac{\vec r(t)}{|\vec r(t)|}$ and hence

$$\begin{align}
\dot{\hat r}(t)&\equiv \frac{d\hat r(t)}{dt}\\\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\vec r(t)}{|\vec r(t)|}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{|\vec r(t)|}\frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}-\frac{\vec r(t)}{|\vec r(t)|^2}\frac{d|\vec r(t)|}{dt}\\\\
&=\frac{\dot{\vec r}(t)}{|\vec r(t)|}-\frac{\vec r(t)}{|\vec r(t)|^2}\,\dot{|\vec r(t)|}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark